# Django delete a file

Tags: python, django

I have the following template that allows me to upload a file and also show the images with a delete button underneath:

```
   <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-0">{{ form.document }}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1 col-md-offset-0"><button type="submit" >Upload</button></div>
    </form>

    {% for image in images %}
    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-0">
        <img style="width: 100%;" src='{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{ username }}/{{image}}'  alt="ID Image"/>
        <div style="text-align: center;"><button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action -->

    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

The view for this template is as follows:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, extra_context={}):
    path="media/" + request.user.username + "/" # insert the path to your directory

    if (os.path.isdir(path)):
        num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)
                     if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
        img_list =os.listdir(path)

    else:

        num_files = 0
        img_list = ""

    username = request.user.username


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
        form_address = ProfileFormAddress()
    return render(request, 'meta/profile.html', {
                  'form': form,
                  'images': img_list,
                  'username': username,
                  'num_files': num_files,
                  'form_address': form_address,
                  })
```

As it stands the delete button does not do anything.  I feel I should be create a form for each button that when clicked will delete the file associated with that button.  If anyone can assist that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely have a form atleast to handle this action.

You can do this in multiple ways.

1. Use the HTTP verb `DELETE` i.e. form with method = "DELETE" and pass in the image name to the parameters. Handle appropriately in your code. Altough for a lot of browsers form submit doesn't work with this.
2. Create a different view /profile//photos//delete and setup a POST and delete.

Not sharing the code as i feel that you would get it.

Comment: Many thanks for the information, I didn't do it in the way you described but your answer got me thinking and came up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bipul got me thinking and I decided that I could make each button a form.  If I named that each form with the filename I could simply loop through each file and simply delete the one which matched the button pressed name.

Template as follows:

```
        {% for image in images %}
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-0">
                <img style="width: 100%;" src='{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{ username }}/{{image}}'  alt="ID Image"/>
                    <div style="text-align: center;"><button type = "submit" name = "{{image}}" class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></div>
            </div>
        </form>
        {% endfor %}
```

View as follows:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, extra_context={}):
    path="media/" + request.user.username + "/" # insert the path to your directory

    if (os.path.isdir(path)):
        num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)
                     if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
        img_list =os.listdir(path)

    else:

        num_files = 0
        img_list = ""

    username = request.user.username

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'upload' in request.POST:
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'address' in request.POST:
        return redirect('profile')
    elif request.method == 'POST':


        for image in img_list:
            if image in request.POST:
                os.remove("media/" + request.user.username + "/" + image)

        return redirect('profile')

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
        form_address = ProfileFormAddress()

    return render(request, 'meta/profile.html', {
                  'form': form,
                  'images': img_list,
                  'username': username,
                  'num_files': num_files,
                  'form_address': form_address,
                  })
```